# Set font color of code output of knitr to black only

Tags: r, knitr

I want to change the font color of the code output of knitr to black for the whole output. The standard output has a grey background and different colors are used in the output for different types of expressions like functions, objects, etc.

My goal is to have a white background and the code should be all black. I already solved the background color problem with the chunk option `background='#FFFFFF'`, but I couldn't find a solution for the font color of the code...

Who can help me?

Thank you very much in advance for your valuabe help!!

Sincerely yours,

broesel

Comment: A custom .css will do it, I think. See http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering

Comment: @DrewSteen perhaps the OP was talking about Rnw (R + LaTeX) instead of Rmd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about Rnw/LaTeX documents, you can turn off syntax highlighting using the chunk option `highlight=FALSE`. See [documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

Comment: Interestingly, I see a dark grey as main/foreground color then, not really a black.